# Get data from mongodb from 1 point to another

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have about 20 million entries in my database and I want to get first 10 000 manipulate and update it. After I'm done I need to get the next 10 000 and so on. But my problem is that I can't find any method that will help me do that. Basically I'm looking for something like this (if exists) find data from 0 to 10000. After I'm done with that data I need to make another request to database find data from 10000 to 20000 and so on.

Comment: Here's a tip: try creating an index for a `version` field. All documents will initially start with a `version` of `null`. With this in mind, we can perform a `find()` on all documents with `version: null` and then `limit(10000)` to retrieve only the first 10,000 results. When updating these documents, we then simply add `$set: {version: 1}`. These documents will then be excluded from subsequent `find()` calls. Additionally, by having this `version` field we can then perform similar actions in the future by finding all documents with `version: 1` and updating them to `version: 2`.

Comment: That's a great idea thank you.

Comment: No problem. If this ends up working for you, please let me know and I'll be sure to submit this as a proper answer. If it doesn't, then I'd be happy to help you think this through some more to find a solution that works :)

Comment: Where did `version` come from?   Does the OP need versioning?   It seems like this is a "cut up a total population of n docs and perform the same operation on them" kind of problem.   Key min/max splitting and so forth.  No?   And what is special about a chunk size of 10,000?

Comment: It can be any number but in my case, I needed 10,000 so I made up an example on that and if I remember correctly every entry in MongoDB has a version by default. I currently don't have this problem that I've posted about but I will have soon and when I tried googling it I couldn't found anything so I asked a question here.